# Spring Boot: Dynamic OAuth2 Client config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to configure Spring Boot OAuth2 with keycloak. Code is working fine when I am using properties from application.properties file. Current config is as follow:

```
rest.security.issuer-uri=http://172.30.30.172:8080/auth/realms/<REALM_NAME>
security.oauth2.resource.id=test
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri=${rest.security.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=${rest.security.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
security.oauth2.resource.jwt.key-value=<PUBLIC KEY>

security.oauth2.client.client-id=<CLIENT ID>
security.oauth2.client.client-secret=<CLIENT SECRET>
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=${rest.security.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=${rest.security.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/token
security.oauth2.client.scope=openid
security.oauth2.client.grant-type=client_credentials
```

I want to configure the client config settings in a dynammic manner by fetching the client config from database for each client (its own realm) request. What should be the Java Spring Boot Security configuration for setting the client properties in dynamic manner.

Current Security configuration is as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "rest.security", value = "enabled", havingValue = "true")
@Import({SecurityProperties.class})
public class SecurityConfigurer extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter{

    private ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProperties;

    private SecurityProperties securityProperties;

    /* Using spring constructor injection, @Autowired is implicit */
    public SecurityConfigurer(ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProperties, SecurityProperties securityProperties) {
        this.resourceServerProperties = resourceServerProperties;
        this.securityProperties = securityProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.resourceId(resourceServerProperties.getResourceId());
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors()
                .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
                .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(securityProperties.getApiMatcher())
                .authenticated();

    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        if (null != securityProperties.getCorsConfiguration()) {
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", securityProperties.getCorsConfiguration());
        }
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenCustomizer jwtAccessTokenCustomizer(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        return new JwtAccessTokenCustomizer(mapper);
    }

}
```

I tried to override bean ResourceServerProperties, using following code. However its throwing NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException exception.

```
@Configuration
@Import({ResourceServerProperties.class})
public class ResourceSecurityProperties {

    @Primary
    @Bean
    ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProperties(){
        ResourceServerProperties resourceServerProperties= new ResourceServerProperties("<CLIENT-ID>", "<CLIENT-SECRET>");
        ResourceServerProperties.Jwt jwt= resourceServerProperties.new Jwt();
        resourceServerProperties.setId("test001001");
        resourceServerProperties.setTokenInfoUri("http://172.30.30.172:8080/auth/realms/conf/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect");
        resourceServerProperties.setUserInfoUri("http://172.30.30.172:8080/auth/realms/conf/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo");
        jwt.setKeyValue("<PUBLIC KEY>");
        resourceServerProperties.setJwt(jwt);
        return resourceServerProperties;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried overriding the bean resourceServerProperties, tried using Primary annotation. However, its still throwing:  Consider marking one of the beans as Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed

Comment: Kartik, how did this go in the end? I believe that something else needs to be overridden in Spring rather than configured...

Comment: I had no chance to verify this, but could be the OAuth2ResourceServerProperties the solution? Looks pretty much like the ResourceServerProperties.